# hist(), plot() in octave shows blank screen

Tags: software-installation, updates, matlab, octave

[image: Take a look]

Code used:

```
x =

   0.17860   0.85981   0.69683   0.56564   0.55712   0.68452   0.83126   0.11530   0.28621   0.75909

>>y
y =

   4.28759   1.07059   1.53263   7.99441   0.98204   3.45242   4.97739   3.38106   4.70819   1.12955

>>plot(x, y)
```

here's the results

```
>>version
ans = 4.2.2
>>graphics_toolkit
ans = qt

$ gnuplot --version
gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2
```

i am new to octave but i feel it is not right

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs (from the `octave` console) of the commands `version` and `graphics_toolkit` and (from the Ubuntu terminal) `gnuplot --version`

Comment: Hmm so it seems like I get the same: try setting `graphics_toolkit('fltk')` or `graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')` as suggested here [Plot generated in Octave is fully black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530224/plot-generated-in-octave-is-fully-black) (both worked for me)

Comment: ... or if you want to stick with the `qt` engine, you can export `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` into your environment before running `octave` as noted here https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51442

Comment: well, that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Add one of these commands in `.octaverc` file in you home directory (create if not already there):

```octave
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");
```

```octave
graphics_toolkit("qt");
```

```octave
graphics_toolkit("fltk");
```